# How do I res.send object to the backend from the front end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to communicate with the frontend to the backend. currently, I have the backend sending an expression to the frontend, and the frontend computes it. from there I want the frontend to send the computed answer back to the backend.

Forexample:
the backend sends "2+2="
the frontend computes that 2+2 = 4
the frontend then sends the answer 4 to the backend
the backend logs the answer 4

Front-end

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
const URL = "http://localhost:5000/"
let firstNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
let secondNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
const express = require('express');
const app = express();



// excecuting random addition
const finalExpression = firstNumber + "+" + secondNumber + "="

console.log(finalExpression);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", URL, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    expression: finalExpression
}))
```

Back-end:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.expression);
  arr = req.body.expression.split("")
  console.log(parseInt(arr[0]) + parseInt(arr[2]))
  // res.send(parseInt(arr[0]) + parseInt(arr[2]))
})

app.listen(5000, () => console.log())
```

as you can see, I tried `res.send` in the frontend to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have mixed things up a little.

1. You can't use `express` on the front-end - it's a node application. You shouldn't need to use `XMLHttpRequest` on the server at all. `express` will handle all the routing for you.
2. You should use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) on the front-end to get/post requests to the server (I've used [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await) here).

It might look a little more like this.

Server:

```
// Send an expression to the front-end
app.get('/getExpression', (req, res) => {
  res.send(expression);
});

app.post('/postResult', (req, res) {
  const result = res.body; 
 
  // Calculate whether the result is correct,
  // and then send the answer back
  res.send(isResultCorrect);
});
```

Client:

```
// To get the expression from the server
const response = await fetch('/getExpression');
const expression = await response.text();

// To post the result back to the server
const options = { type: 'POST', body: result };
const response = await fetch('/postResult', options);
const isResultCorrect = await response.text();
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this version. The version I have does what I need. I just want to send back the result of the calculation to the backend.

Comment: Have you labelled your code incorrectly in your question?

Comment: The Producer(backend) generats random addition expressions of two positive integers, e.g. "2+3=" The consumer(frontend) computing and returns the correct mathematical. I may have mixed up my idea of what producer and consumer are. I am not sure

Comment: I've fixed your labelling which was getting everyone confused :)

Answer (score 0):

You invert frontend and backend :) It is the frontend that sends the XMLHTTPREQUEST and it is the server that processes the request and returns the response.

This being said, using res.send is the right solution to return a response. You did the right thing in BACKEND. Therefore, you can uncomment the `// res.send(parseInt(arr[0]) + parseInt(arr[2]))` and leave the backend code as it is.

What is missing in the FRONTEND is a code to listen to and handle this response :

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(xhr.response);
    }
}
```

Add it after `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();`

Your code should then look like this :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// New code added here
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
       // Handle the response (ex: console.log it)
       console.log(xhr.response);
    }
}

xhr.open("POST", URL, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    expression: finalExpression
}))
```

Comment: the thing is, it is more complex than that. the way I have it is;
The Producer(backend) generats random addition expressions of two positive integers, e.g. "2+3="
The consumer(frontend) computing and returning the correct mathematical.
I may have them mixed up. I am not sure

Comment: Hey, thank you for fixing that :)
However, after uncommenting ```res.send(parseInt(arr[0]) + parseInt(arr[2]))``` , I am getting this error ```express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead index.js:9:7```

Comment: Glad I could help you! As stated in the express doc :

`res.send()`  Accept parameter that can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, Boolean, or an Array. 

In your case you're passing a integer parameter.

So convert the result to string or send an object

`res.send((parseInt(arr[0]) + parseInt(arr[2])).toString())` 

OR
`res.send({result: parseInt(arr[0]) + parseInt(arr[2])})`

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. :)

now when I implemented this ```xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState) {
       console.log(xhr.response);
    }
}
```

I get the response ```"2+2 = null null 4"```
how do I get rid of "null null"

Comment: What happen  if you surround the `console.log(xhr.response)` by this condition: `if (xhr.status === 200) { ...}` ?